# kendo ui grid selecting row ID

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I can't get the Kendo UI grid to work properly.  All I am trying to do is, when it is double clicked, I want it to redirect to action.

```
<div class="Grid" id="Grid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grdWorkFlow")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.SablonWorkflowID).Visible(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
    columns.Bound(p => p.DateAdded);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Active);

}).Events(events => events.Change("grid_selected"))
.Selectable(p => p.Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.SablonWorkflowID))
.Create("Yeni", "Workflow")
)

)
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function grid_selected(e) {
    var grid = $('#Grid').data('grdWorkFlow'); 
    alert('1');
    var record = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); 
    alert('2');
    var WID = record.SablonWorkflowID;

    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit","Workflow",new { wID = 'WID' })"; 
}

$("#grdWorkFlow").on("dblclick", "tr.k-state-selected", function (e) {
    // do something
});
```

This is my code.  I don't get to alert('2').  I have tried various versions of this, using all types of different stuff from the net.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should define `grid` as:

```
var grid = $('#grdWorkFlow').data('kendoGrid');
```

Comment: Hi Ona,  That was the first thing i tried and when it didn't work I looked for other ways.  I am going to try it again to make sure i didn't miss anything with spelling...

Comment: var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');  You can try like this.